# Safely importing models in django's middleware

Tags: django

I have been trying to import a model in a middleware process function but I am getting the error:
`Value: Model class x doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS`

I am guessing the problem is that the application setup is not complete, however, all my attempts to solve this have hit a wall.

## middleware.py function

```
from notifications.models import Notification
    ...

class CheckNotificationMiddleware(object):

    """
    Checks clicked notification to mark it as read
    """
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():

            notification_id = request.GET.get('notification_id')
            if notification_id:
                AppConfig.get_model('Notification')
                try:

                    notification = Notification.objects.get(
                        pk=notification_id, status=0, recipient=request.user)
                    notification.status = 1
                    notification.save()
                except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                    pass
```

## settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
    'notifications',
...
)
```

I have tried a couple of things including...

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
AppConfig.get_model('Notification')
```

I am using Django version 1.11 and python 2.7

Comment: I'm not sure why you are trying to use AppConfig here. You have already imported the Notification model at the top of the file; just use it.

Comment: When I use it (`Notification`), I get the error `Value: Model class x doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: *Where* do you get that error? Show the full traceback and the actual code you used.

Answer (score 0):

you have to include `notifications` under the

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'notifications',
]
```

in the settings file